# Flip a Data Frame in Pandas and keep one column's values as the new row's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, time-series

I currently have a Data Frame that looks like so when I read it in:

| Date | Country | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | AFG | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 01/02/2020 | AFG | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 01/03/2020 | AFG | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 01/01/2020 | USA | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 01/02/2020 | USA | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I would like to transform it into the form below, whereby the country becomes the row's index, date replaces the columns, and the values of Column A go onto fill the date's respective value for each country.

| Country | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | ... | 04/25/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 0 | 2 | 1 | ... | 5 |
| USA | 2 | 4 | 9 | ... | 15 |

I have tried to use group-by before but nothing appears to be working quite in the way shown above. Am I forgetting a command or is there some way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

1. TRY `pivot_table` to get the required.
2. Use `rename_axis` to remove the axis name.
3. Finally reset the index via `reset_index()`.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Date', values='A', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Country  01/01/2020  01/02/2020  01/03/2020
0     AFG           0           2           1
1     USA           2           4           0
```